# Algorithm for finding the best pairs

Tags: algorithm

I've pulled this algorithm question out of an idea that was being discussed at a forum in January, 2012.  You can see details of that here: http://caribbeanopendata.ideascale.com/a/dtd/Underserved-Community-Internet-Access-Baskets-for-BWA-Licensees/85150-16663

I've framed it like this:

> A block is defined as a region that has a value v, and a population
>   size, p. A basket, b is defined as a pair of blocks.
>
> Given 12 blocks, find the best pair wise distribution - based on value
>   - of those blocks into baskets.
>
> **EDIT**: The best pair must not be significantly better than the worst pair. That is, what  is sought is not just the best average, but
>   actually the best distribution of value (total area/total number of households).

What algorithm should I look into to solve that question?

Comment: SInce their are only 11*10*9*8*7 possibilities, I'd try them all and keep  the "best" one.

Comment: What is criteria for `best pair wise distribution`? Do baskets have any constraints, like summation of population should be less that `x`?

Comment: Sabbir, I edited the constraints a bit

Comment: What is the value of a pair ? The sum of the values of the two blocks ?

Comment: @Edouard, yes, one basket has a value equal to the sum

Comment: In that case, the best pair-wise distribution is to pair the highest value block with the lowest value block, second highest with second lowest, etc. I think your definition of the problem is lacking. How does population size affect the value? How would you mathematically define the value of a basket in terms of v1, p1, v2, and p2? The condition in your edit is also impossible to satisfy - if one block has value 1000 and the others have value 1, any distribution will break this rule. Maybe I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Svinja, value, I've come to understand is "total area/total number of households"

Comment: Also, @wildplasser, my thinking is that there are 132 pairs possible. And since we want the best group of 6 pairs, this looks like 132C6 = 6547258432 arrangements.

Comment: On second thought, it looks more like 11*9*7*5*3 = 10395 possible pairings. Maybe I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Edmonds Blossom V algorithm to find the maximum matching. This algorithm is used in job applications too. When you have 100 worker and 100 job offer what is the best matching when the worker have more then 1 skill. Usually the best matching is when you can apply some other logic then just lexicographic sorting.